# python: get file path and create a new file in the same directory

Tags: python

So I know how to get a location of the needed file, I'm doing this with

```
file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_full_name))[0]
```

but what I need to do is:

1. Get the file name, which I have
2. Get path of the file, which I also know how to get
3. Create a file in the same directory with a modified name, for example lets say I have a file called "data.csv" on Desktop. I would need to create a file called "data - results.csv" to Desktop.

I have only tried printing the new name, but the only result I have got with this code:

```
    myresultcsvfile = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_name))[0] + " - results.csv"
```

is this:

```
myfile: ('Book1 - Copy', ' - results.csv')
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong but I cant figure out what. And that's just the file name, I also need to add full path of the parent file to it (so that the end result would be "C:\users[username]\desktop\Book1 - copy - results.csv" in this case)

Comment: Have you tried just `os.path.splitext(file_full_name)[0] + " - results.csv"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
full = 'C:\\ .. put here your path .. \\data.csv'
dir_name = os.path.dirname(full)
file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(full))[0]
output_file = dir_name + '\\' + file_name + ' - results.csv'
```